# What's the signature structure in TLS server key exchange message?

Tags: tls, rsa

I'm writing a TLS server. While handling ECDHE-RSA cipher suite, the server key exchange is needed. According to [Elliptic Curve Cryptography (ECC) Cipher Suites for Transport Layer Security (TLS)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4492)

```
    select (KeyExchangeAlgorithm) {
        case ec_diffie_hellman:
            ServerECDHParams    params;
            Signature           signed_params;
    } ServerKeyExchange;

NOTE: SignatureAlgorithm is "rsa" for the ECDHE_RSA key exchange
algorithm and "anonymous" for ECDH_anon.  These cases are defined in
TLS [2][3].

[2]   Dierks, T. and C. Allen, "The TLS Protocol Version 1.0",
     RFC 2246, January 1999.

[3]   Dierks, T. and E. Rescorla, "The Transport Layer Security (TLS)
     Protocol Version 1.1", RFC 4346, April 2006.
```

So I checked TLS 1.0 & 1.1, in [TLS 1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346)

```
  struct {
      select (KeyExchangeAlgorithm) {
          case diffie_hellman:
              ServerDHParams params;
              Signature signed_params;
          case rsa:
              ServerRSAParams params;
              Signature signed_params;
      };
  } ServerKeyExchange;

  struct {
      select (SignatureAlgorithm) {
          case anonymous: struct { };
          case rsa:
              digitally-signed struct {
                  opaque md5_hash[16];
                  opaque sha_hash[20];
              };
          case dsa:
              digitally-signed struct {
                  opaque sha_hash[20];
              };
          };
      };
  } Signature;
```

So far as I understand, I should use:

```
digitally-signed struct {
    opaque md5_hash[16];
    opaque sha_hash[20];
};
```

And what's this digitally-signed structure? I also saw some examples using sha512, is md5 really necessary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#Digitally-signed struct for RSA signing

> And what's this digitally-signed structure?

It's defined in TLS 1.1's [Section 4.7. *Cryptographic Attributes*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346#section-4.7):

> In RSA signing, a 36-byte structure of two hashes (one SHA and one MD5) is signed (encrypted with the private key).  It is encoded with PKCS #1 block type 1, as described in [PKCS1A].

#MD5 hash in digitally-signed struct

> I also saw some examples using sha512, is md5 really necessary?

Yes, it is set to be this MD5/SHA-1 combination in TLS 1.1. This is something that was only changed in TLS 1.2. There the cipher suite gets to choose the hash.

From TLS 1.2's [Section 1.2. *Major Differences from TLS 1.1*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-1.2):

> - The MD5/SHA-1 combination in the digitally-signed element has been
>   replaced with a single hash.  Signed elements now include a field
>   that explicitly specifies the hash algorithm used.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. After checked PKCS1A, I found [Using SHA2 Algorithms with Cryptographic Message Syntax](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5754) is quite useful. I'm trying to understand the meaning of `id-sha512: 30 0b 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 03`. `30` means 'sequence' in ASN.1, `0b` is the length(11), `06` means 'object identifier', `09` is the length(9), but what is this `60 86 48`? I can guess the later sequence `01 65 03 04 02 03` means 'organization(1) gov(101) csor(3) nistalgorithm(4) hashalgs(2) 3'.

Comment: No real idea. Best put it in a new, separate question.